# Huawei Matebook 14 No sound and no microphone input

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, huawei

I just got a brand new Matebook 14 with AMD Ryzen 17 Raedon Graphics and 16GB RAM.
After installing ubuntu fresh I have tested the sound but the speakers are not working.
I have seen different solutions online and tested them all, but unfotunately non helped me so that's why I am asking now here.
The sound card is being recognzied by the system but for some reason no output from the sounds and also no input.
When pluging in headphones they also don't work, so hearing music works only with bluetoth headset.
I have tried the Linux mint distro and deepin(the distro from huawei) also but the same issue on all of them.
And in Windows everything works fine :
Thank you very much for any usefull answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and based on the materials I found, I wrote a daemon that solves it.

### Problem

The headphone and speaker channels are mixed up in the sound card driver for Linux distributions.

When headphones are connected, the system considers that sound should be output from the speakers. When the headphones are off, the system tries to output sound through them.

#### Problem details (found [here](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3350#issuecomment-1301070327))

Looks like there is some weird hardware design, because from my prospective, the interesting widgets are:

- 0x01 - Audio Function Group
- 0x10 - Headphones DAC (really both devices connected here)
- 0x11 - Speaker DAC
- 0x16 - Headphones Jack
- 0x17 - Internal Speaker

And:

- widgets 0x16 and 0x17 simply should be connected to different DACs 0x10 and 0x11, but Internal Speaker 0x17 ignores the connection select command and use the value from Headphones Jack 0x16.
- Headphone Jack 0x16 is controlled with some weird stuff so it should be enabled with GPIO commands for Audio Group 0x01.
- Internal Speaker 0x17 is coupled with Headphone Jack 0x16 so it should be explicitly disabled with EAPD/BTL Enable command.

### Solution

A daemon has been implemented that monitors the connection/disconnection of headphones and accesses the sound card device in order to switch playback to the right place.

You can get installer in my github repo: https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have tried it but unsuccessfull.

When checking the logs all I see is:
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
Headphones connected (even I didn't connect them)
Invalid card number 'get'. 

The thing is that even when I plug in my earphones I can't listen anything, no sound at all also from speakers

Comment: Did you try `pulseaudio --start`?